# My FragmentActivity is not receiving broadcasts

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-fragmentactivity

I registered a BroadcastReceiver in my FragmentActivity like so:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setMapLocations(intent);
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setMapLocations(intent);
        }
    };
```

and start the receiver is onStart():

```
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((mMessageReceiver),
            new IntentFilter("MyNotificationData"));
    }
```

and my broadcast sender is defined in the manifest as follows:

```
    <service
        android:name=".TrackerMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The problem is that onReceive() never gets hit, even though the exact same code worked fine in an AppCompatActivity in the same app. Any idea what's going on? Do broadcast services not play well with FragmentActivity?

Comment: Show the code where the app send a broadcast receiver with "MyNotificationData" action. By the way, the manifest you posted is not related to the broadcast receiver.

Comment: @SonTruong I'm not sure why you say that. This is the documented way to declare a FirebaseMessagingService.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, but I was able to get around the issue by leaving the BroadcastReceiver code in the AppCompatActivity. In that case, both BroadcastReceivers got hit.